# "significantly so" grammar construction

Tags: grammar, word-usage, phrases, emphasis

I have encountered some occurrences of phrases of the type:

> the correlation between variables is strong, and significantly so...

and was asked to explain what the part after the comma meant. Although I know the meaning, I couldn't give a precise answer despite searching for a formal description.

Could someone please explain what the construction used here is and provide some more examples (which do not use the word *significantly* but have the same construction).

Comment: It is a common construction that is  *used to refer back to something that has already been mentioned*: 
*‘Is he coming?’ ‘I hope so.’ (I hope  he is coming) - 
‘Did they mind?’ ‘I don't think so.’ - 
If she notices, she never says so.* - The correlation is strong in a significant way.

Comment: In the example provided, the context seems to be statistical analysis. I'm not sure if this is an accident, because the word "signficant" carries a particular meaning here (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_significance).

This means it may be difficult to express the same meaning in the same construction without using this term. The meaning of the term "significantly" in this context would need to be expressed in some other way that described further concepts relevant to the statistically "significant" result.

Comment: @remnant - I guess the question is about the use of "so" rather than "significantly".

Comment: No verb with so! I think if the OP gives the complete sentence, it would be more helpful.

Comment: If the question is about the use of "so", this definition from Merriam-Webster may help: 
"in a manner or way indicated or suggested".
In the example given, the correlation is described as "strong". The adjective "strong" is then intensified by an adverbial phrase "significantly so" =  "significantly in the manner or way indicated" = "significantly strong".

Comment: @mahmudkoya The sentence can be considered complete, no extra verb is needed.

Comment: @Josh yes, that is correct, the question is about the word "so".

Comment: @remnant The word significant didn't have to do with its statistical meaning, it was just an accident. The following definition you posted makes a lot of sense, thanks for the info.

Comment: @KevinLiu - does my initial comment answer your question? http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*So* here is a predicate adjective, "mirroring" *strong*. Thus, *significantly* is an adverb modifying an adjective. (How strong? Significantly strong.)

A similar example:

The loud music is deafeningly so.

It is not necessary that *so* be an adjective:

The man runs quickly, and astonishingly so. (Used here as an adverb modifier—*so* is here an adverb)